# Error in checking the existence of a sublist in a list from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to check if all elements in a sublist exist in a list so I created this extension:

```
extension StringExtension on List<dynamic> {
  bool containsAll(List<dynamic> sublist) {
    for (var element in sublist) {
      if (!this.contains(element)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

But when I run it like this :

```
documments[index]['Read'].containsAll(group.members)
```

> Read is a list of string in firebase cloud

It gives me this error:

```
Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'containsAll'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList' 
Tried calling: containsAll(Instance(length:3) of '_GrowableList')
```

This is how the code appears in the VSC, it looks like the function isn't detected by the VSC :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you imported your file with extension class to file where you are using it?

Comment: @OlgaP, I did and I put some images to show it

Comment: Can you please show us what versions of dart you have declared in your pubspec.yaml? Extensions weren't introduced until dart 2.7, so certain versions of android studio and vscode's flutter plugins sometimes won't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly where's the problem, but I reverse the comparison and it works just fine now

For :

```
documments[index]['Read'].containsAll(group.members)
```

to

```
group.members.containsAllBack(documments[index]['Read'])
```